# Outline border for a range of cells in exceljs?

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I come across this use case where I have to give outline borders for a range of cells (Start: A1 to C5 and End: A4 to C5) and I searched google for results but not getting properly. I want an outer border for a particular range and I used the below snippet code but not working

```
Code:
const workbook = new Workbook();    
      const loeTermsandConditionsWorksheet1 = workbook.addWorksheet('(dummy) page',{views:[
        {activeCell: 'A1', showGridLines:true}
        ]})
 //OUTER BRODER STARTS
      const createOuterBorder = (loeTermsandConditionsWorksheet1, start = {row: 1, col: 5}, end = {row: 4, col: 5}, borderWidth = 'medium') => {
        const borderStyle = {
            style: borderWidth
        };
        for (let i = start.row; i <= end.row; i++) {
            const leftBorderCell = loeTermsandConditionsWorksheet1.getCell(i, start.col);
            const rightBorderCell = loeTermsandConditionsWorksheet1.getCell(i, end.col);
            leftBorderCell.border = {
                ...leftBorderCell.border,
                left: borderStyle
            };
            rightBorderCell.border = {
                ...rightBorderCell.border,
                right: borderStyle
            };
        }
    
        for (let i = start.col; i <= end.col; i++) {
            const topBorderCell = loeTermsandConditionsWorksheet1.getCell(start.row, i);
            const bottomBorderCell = loeTermsandConditionsWorksheet1.getCell(end.row, i);
            topBorderCell.border = {
                ...topBorderCell.border,
                top: borderStyle
            };
            bottomBorderCell.border = {...bottomBorderCell.border, bottom: borderStyle};
        }
      
    };
    
    //OUTER BRODER END
```

this is what I am expecting:

[image: Example image]

but not getting the correct result.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what your incorrect result is. But i use this for outer borders and it works as well! Original Link: [ExcelJS Outline border issue](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/333)

```js
const createOuterBorder = (worksheet, start = {row: 1, col: 1}, end = {row: 1, col: 1}, borderWidth = 'medium') => {

    const borderStyle = {
        style: borderWidth
    };
    for (let i = start.row; i <= end.row; i++) {
        const leftBorderCell = worksheet.getCell(i, start.col);
        const rightBorderCell = worksheet.getCell(i, end.col);
        leftBorderCell.border = {
            ...leftBorderCell.border,
            left: borderStyle
        };
        rightBorderCell.border = {
            ...rightBorderCell.border,
            right: borderStyle
        };
    }

    for (let i = start.col; i <= end.col; i++) {
        const topBorderCell = worksheet.getCell(start.row, i);
        const bottomBorderCell = worksheet.getCell(end.row, i);
        topBorderCell.border = {
            ...topBorderCell.border,
            top: borderStyle
        };
        bottomBorderCell.border = {
            ...bottomBorderCell.border,
            bottom: borderStyle
        };
    }
};
```

I use it like this:

```js
createOuterBorder(
    worksheet,
    (start = { row: 2, col: 2 }),
    (end = { row: 5, col: 5 })
  );
```

The result (see the image) is start on cell 2, row 2 (index here is 1 not 0!) and end on cell 5, row 5.

I see your code looks almost like mine. Well, maybe you just called the method wrong?

[image]

Greetings, Florian

Comment: This is essentially a link only answer. If the link rots, this answer is worthless.

Comment: Thx, I corrected my answer with sample code and better description.